# XSLT: Iterating through a folder set to create HTML table rows

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and have done a ton of searching and couldn't find anything to reference for what I'm trying to do.

The automation tool I use for regression software produces a set of folders (called T00001, T00002, T00003, ..., T00010, etc) each with 4 .xml files that hold data containing automated test runs (essentially PASS/FAIL status and error logs).

I'm attempting to use a for-each statement to iterate through the folder set and create table rows that parse in certain node data to compile into a test run HTML report. This is an example of one of my failed attempts (using XPath's 'is-dir() function):

```
<xsl:for-each select="folder()">
    <fn:if test="is-dir($base)=true()">
        <tr>
            <xsl:variable name="result" select="document('/Result.xml')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="output" select="document('/Output.xml')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="test" select="document(concat(.,'Test.xml'))"/>
            <th bgcolor="#D3D3D3" scope="row"><xsl:value-of select="$test/Project/Plans/Plan/Nodes/Node/Node/Name"/></th>
            <xsl:variable name="status" select="$result/Result/Status"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$status = 'Failed'">
                <td bgcolor="#FF4500"><xsl:text>FAILED</xsl:text></td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$status = 'Passed'">
                <td bgcolor="#90EE90"><xsl:text>PASSED</xsl:text></td>
            </xsl:if>
            <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="$output/Output/Line">
                <ul>
                <xsl:if test="@Type='Error'">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></li>
                </xsl:if>
                </ul>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </fn:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have managed to path into the correct directory using code not included in this example but have yet to discover a "for-each" loop that will allow me to iterate through each folder within the set (and create a table row for each folder).

I am using xslt 3.0 to write this script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That code doesn't look like pure XSLT 3.0, it seems you are using extension elements (e.g. `fn:if`) and/or extension functions (e.g. `is-dir`) that are perhaps provided by some particular application. Add a tag for that application.

Comment: Hi Martin!

It's not, I was attempting to integrate some XPath into my code and that's an artifact of a failed use of that. My namespace declarations look like the following (though I am not using all of the references):

<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:user="http://tempuri.org/msxsl">

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use, where do you expect the `folder` or `is-dir` function to come from (EXPath?)?

Comment: Turns out that neither of them had that function, and after reviewing what I was trying to do with someone better at coding than I am they told me to compile a master XML using ElementTree in Python and parse what I needed out of there.

I'm new to StackOverflow and am not 100% certain how to resolve this ticket but I will attempt to close it out. Thanks anyways for the help!